# Is there any way to avoid parse-errors in pycparser library of python

Tags: python, pycparser

The below code triggers an error in .c file when `pycparser` tries to parse it. This might be because `rf_wcdma_bup_flags_t` is not a defined typedef, is there anyway to skip it?

```
rf_wcdma_bup_flags_t rf_wcdma_debug_flags = { 0 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to skip it. However, it's easy to support new types by adding "fake headers" to the analysis flow with `pycparser`. The [README page](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser) has some details about this - and [this blog post](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/on-parsing-c-type-declarations-and-fake-headers/) has more.